# Dynamic @Where parameter

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, where-clause

Is there a way to provide a dynamic parameter to be used on the @Where annotation ?

So far i haven't been able to find any help on the documentation

Something similar to

```java
@Where(clause = "someField = {dynamic.field}")
```

This would greatly diminish the amount of refactoring on my code.

Comment: I think you may achieve same result with filters( @Filter) check https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-dynamic-mapping

Comment: Awesome @özkanpakdil, it does have the functionally that i am looking for, too bad it breaks caching :( other drawback is the fact that we have to enable and disable it manually

Comment: out of curiosity did you try to use it like @Where(clause = "someField = : dynamic_field") because it may work :) I have been reading hibernate code and I did not see anything against it. hmm at the sametime you will need to provide this parameter how :) hmm it may not work

Comment: i did @özkanpakdil, but to no avail, he kept complaining that he didnt understand the parameter